# USB B plugged in a desktop collects files from USB A

Tags: windows, usb, user-profiles

I was always wondering the below scenario

**Scenario:** A USB stick (USB 1) is plugged in the USB port of a computer.

Is it possible to connect another USB stick ( USB 2) in another usb port of the desktop, which will automatically collect the files of USB 1?

Is there any other type of device which collects the files of USB 1 , given that we can't log in in the specific user profile of the desktop??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *collects the files*?

Comment: By *"automatically"* do you mean without installing any kind of software that would actually accomplish this copying task? Do you expect an external hardware device to initiate a data or file transfer?

Comment: I mean transfer all the files from one usb to the other

Answer (score -1):

No, not without the aid of a computer. USB sticks are "dumb" devices. So you need a different computer than the one you cannot log into.

Comment: @Ramhound *"There are malicious USB devices that collect keystrokes."* -- You exaggerate the capability.  There is no USB device that can force the PC host to send it data.  That kind of capability only happens in spy movies and TV.

Comment: @Ramhound -- I am well aware of composite USB gadgets that can provide multiple functions to the PC host.  So I don't dispute the reality of keyboard + storage.  But that is not *"collecting keystrokes"* by the mechanism the OP specifies, i.e. by plugging in another USB device.  Try staying on topic.

Comment: “USB sticks are "dumb" devices.” - I am downvoting this answer due to this incorrect misleading false statement.

Comment: There is nothing on a retail stick that one would purchase. These are the sticks I called “dumb” and they are (unspecialized sticks)

Comment: You members are sponsoring specialized sticks and I to not think the author is using such specialized sticks. Your post are off track as the author is using regular keys

Comment: @Ramhound, a USB device cannot collect anything on its own, only an intelligent host can do. In this sense a USB stick is "dumb". However, a USB stick can contain malicious executable, and if the host is idiotically configured to auto-execute the initial code (which used to be a default on many Windows systems) on plug-in, the code can run and collect everything. But the stick needs a host OS to perform this action, so the poster's statement is not incorrect or misleading.

Comment: @Ale..chenski - We will have to agree to disagree.  I have personally seen a USB device report itself as a storage device (with working storage) but also have the capabilities of another type of USB device.